# Displaying Arraylist on Listview trouble

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, listview, arraylist

So I have an app that will let you create a java object containing information about a pill you take (Name, dose amount, number of doses per day, and number of pills left).  I then store this information of firebase real-time database, then I use a separate activity to get the information from the database and store it in an array list, which i want to be displayed in a list view.Current issue is that the list view is not showing all data of array list, only the last pill object that was added.

Code for the uploading of data:

```
package com.example.andrew.pilltracker;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.auth.*;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class SecondActvty extends AppCompatActivity {

static String ref = "Advil";
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference mRootRef;
int id = 1;

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
               Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActvty.this, MainActivityController.class);
               startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:

                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
               Intent intent1 = new Intent(SecondActvty.this, ThirdActivity.class);
               startActivity(intent1);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_view);

    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mRootRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //id++;

            EditText pillName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pillName);
            EditText pillDose = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pillDose);
            EditText pillCount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pillCount);
            EditText doseDuration = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.doseDuration);

            String name = pillName.getText().toString();
            String dose = pillDose.getText().toString();
            String day = doseDuration.getText().toString();
            String count = pillCount.getText().toString();
            ref = name;


            Pill pill = new Pill();
            pill.setName(name);
            pill.setCount(count);
            pill.setDay(day);
            pill.setDose(dose);


           if(!name.equals("") && !dose.equals("") && !day.equals("") && !count.equals("")) {
                mRootRef.child("pills").child(name).setValue(pill);
                toastMessage("Success!");
                pillName.setText("");
                pillCount.setText("");
                doseDuration.setText("");
                pillDose.setText("");
            }
                else {
               toastMessage("Please fill all fields");
           }
        }
    });
}
private void toastMessage(String message){
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public static String getReference(){
        return ref;
    }


}
```

And the class that will download the data from firebase and show it in the listview:

```
package com.example.andrew.pilltracker;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivityController extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView mTextMessage;

private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference mRootRef;
private ArrayList<String> array;
private ListView mListView;
private ArrayAdapter adapter;




private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_home);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivityController.this, SecondActvty.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_view);

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    array = new ArrayList<String>();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);


    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mRootRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();

    mTextMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

    mRootRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           showData(dataSnapshot);
            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });



}

private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){


        Pill pInfo = new Pill();

        pInfo.setName(ds.child(SecondActvty.getReference().toString()).getValue(Pill.class).getName());
        pInfo.setCount(ds.child(SecondActvty.getReference().toString()/*Integer.toString(databaseRef)*/).getValue(Pill.class).getCount());
        pInfo.setDose(ds.child(SecondActvty.getReference().toString()).getValue(Pill.class).getDose());
        pInfo.setDay(ds.child(SecondActvty.getReference().toString()).getValue(Pill.class).getDay());

        array.add(pInfo.getName());
        array.add("Number of Pills Left: " + pInfo.getCount());
        array.add("Number of Pills per Dose: " + pInfo.getDose());
        array.add("Number of Doses per Day: " + pInfo.getDay());
    }
}

//Database shit
@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();


}

}
```

Database structure:
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yt5az.png)

Comment: Please attach your database structure with example data stored in it and remove the first instance of code.

Comment: @PradyumanDixit I have attached a picture of the database at the bottom of the post.  I don't know what you mean by remove the first instance of code.  Thanks!

Comment: I mean remove the first code you've put for setting the values in database, if there is no problem with that. Also don't put your firebase URL in images, it can be misused.

Comment: Hey @AndrewHunter, do mark the answer as correct by clicking tick mark type V shaped button next to the answer, it should turn green. This helps future readers of the question and I'd appreciate that too. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with setting up the adapter. You've given the array in the adapter before adding the actual values and you're getting it done inside the `onDataChange()` method.

That's why only the last pill data is getting displayed. To solve the problem please use the following lines of code:

```java
mRootRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){


               Pill pInfo = new Pill();

               pInfo.setName(ds.child(SecondActvty.getReference().toString()).getValue(Pill.class).getName());
               pInfo.setCount(ds.child(SecondActvty.getReference().toString()/*Integer.toString(databaseRef)*/).getValue(Pill.class).getCount());
               pInfo.setDose(ds.child(SecondActvty.getReference().toString()).getValue(Pill.class).getDose());
               pInfo.setDay(ds.child(SecondActvty.getReference().toString()).getValue(Pill.class).getDay());

               array.add(pInfo.getName());
               array.add("Number of Pills Left: " + pInfo.getCount());
               array.add("Number of Pills per Dose: " + pInfo.getDose());
               array.add("Number of Doses per Day: " + pInfo.getDay());
           }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        } // don't ignore errors, do something for this too

         adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
         mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    });
```